# How to Open web browser when I logged into the PC

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I'm developing a web application. There is a requirement to open the web application through the default web browser when he/she logged to the pc using his/her user account. And I need to extract the his domain username and I need to pass it to the web application.

I try to do this using c#.net windows services but it didn't work.

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)

 {
   string target = "http://www.microsoft.com";


        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(target);
        }
        catch
            (
             System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception noBrowser)
        {
           // if (noBrowser.ErrorCode == -2147467259)
              //  MessageBox.Show(noBrowser.Message);
        }
        catch (System.Exception other)
        {
           // MessageBox.Show(other.Message);
        }

    }
```

Do you know how to do this using windows services or any other solutions ?

Comment: what is the role of java tag here?

Comment: there can be a solution using java :D

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for windows authentication, you can try [this msdn link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/36e1bcfa-a46a-47a8-8b21-78357efe866b/how-to-get-windows-login-credentials-using-cnet)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put a short cut to the website in the Start Menu Startup Folder; [Run a program automatically when Windows starts](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows-vista/run-a-program-automatically-when-windows-starts)

Then your website just needs to use the [windows authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx#paght000025_overview).